# Can't change my master branch to main locally

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I really need some help regarding branch renaming.

Unfortunately I can't push on github with the main branch, I have to use the master branch because I can't locally change my branch name.

I need to commit once to be able to use this command : `git branch -M main`.

But if I create a new file and put a git init, the display branch will be master and running `git branch -M main` will lead me to this error :

```
error: refname refs/heads/master not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

I would like to know if there is any other ways to rename the branch locally to main without renaming manually after each file creation.

Comment: You need to specify both the `source` and `target` branches: `git branch --move master main`

Comment: You said you need to commit once, but it appears you didn't do that.

Comment: And if you can't use "main" and have to use "master", why do you try to rename your branch from "master" to "main"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Make a commit, or use `git checkout --orphan main` (or `git switch --orphan main`), or use `git init -b main` if you have that.

## Long-ish

In a new, totally-empty Git repository, Git is in a somewhat strange state:

- A *branch name* like `master` or `main` must contain the hash ID of some valid, existing commit.
- No commits exist yet.

Therefore, no branch names can exist yet.

Nonetheless, `git status` will tell you that you are `on branch master`, for instance.  This is the strange state: you're *on a branch that does not exist*.

In recent versions of Git, `git branch -m` and `git branch -M`—both of which rename a branch—were smartened up so that they can rename this nonexistent branch.  If you have one of these recent versions of Git (2.30 or later), `git branch -m main` will work in this state.

Older versions of Git, however, only allow you to rename a branch that actually *exists*.  So in this case, to use `git branch -m main`, you must, as you said:

> commit once

Note that you need only make *one* commit, so that the commit exists, so that the branch name exists.  It's the act of *creating a commit* while *in this state* that creates the branch name.  The branch name is there, it's just that it doesn't exist.  Then you run `git commit`, and now the branch name is there and *does* exist.  The new commit you just made is a *root commit:* a commit with no parent.  And that's all there is to it.

**You don't have to use `git branch -m` to rename this unborn branch.**  If you *do* want to use `git branch -m` to rename it, it must be an *existing* branch, but you can rename it *before it exists*.  You just need to use some other command, in Git versions before 2.30.

In Git version 2.28 or later, `git init` takes `--initial-branch` (or `-b` for short) which allows you to specify the name of the branch that doesn't exist, but that you're on.  So `git init -b main` does the trick.

If your Git predates 2.28, you can run `git init` as usual, then use the checkout or switch command with the `--orphan` flag.  This creates a branch that does not exist yet.  This flag has worked since Git 1.7.2: its purpose is to re-create that peculiar state in which you're on a branch that does not exist.  The *next* commit you make then creates that branch, by creating a root commit and storing the new commit's hash ID in the branch name as usual.  The storing of the hash ID creates the branch name and the peculiar situation, of being on a branch that does not exist, is now resolved.

Note that when you're on a branch that does not exist and you use `git checkout --orphan`, you change the name of the branch that does not exist.  The old name continues not to exist, so the fact that you *were* going to create that branch with a future commit is now forgotten: Git has no idea that `master` never sprang into existence, and won't go create it.  It will instead create this *other* name that does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

To change the name from `master` to `main` locally before even makeing a commit.follow these steps:-

1. Navigate to the directory where your project sits.
2. It will  show hidden file since by default, .git would be hidden.
3. Inside .git, there is a file, `HEAD`, open it in a text editor.
4. You'd see, `ref: refs/heads/master`.
5. change master to main in  `ref: refs/heads/master`.

It will rename the master branch as main.

Comment: You *can* do this, but `git checkout --orphan main` is easier.