# How to github commit changes from local directory to remote without cloning step by step?

Tags: github, commit

I have a github repository and a local directory with changes without any .git directories in it.
I want to commit my changes.
I can clone github and then copy files there but this would change modification dates of the files which I don't want.

What I did:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://...
git fetch origin
git add .
git status - shows all files as new
git diff origin/main - shows the correct changes I want to commit
```

I then did

```
git commit -m 'My first commit'
```

and after this my local branch became master and status would not show anything anymore.

I know this may be something really basic but I couldn't really find any guide how to do this.

**UPDATE:** I have found a tricky but simple workaround for this. In some other directory I do:

```
git clone  https://...
```

Then copy .git directory to my real working directory and:

```
git add .
git status
```

And volia! All the changes are there.

As far as I understand by now, with "git init, get remote add, git fetch.." I will end up creating an empty local repository and will have to do a first commit to it. Which will result in a "merged commit" on the github which will consist of 2 commits: 1st initial, and 2nd real. Which would look very messy with this "initial"..

Answer (score 0):

> copy files there but this would change modification dates

Use **pax**(1).  Something like

```
$ pax -rw modfied.c working_tree/
```

will copy the files without changing the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, since you didn't clone the remote repository, your local repo doesn't know what you want to push to. In other words, your branch has no target. You can [set the upstream](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/2.13.7) like this:

```
git branch -u origin main
```

Then try your git status/git push again. It should know what to compare to and push to now.

## Update

First, let me walk through the initial question again to point out the exact situation we're now in after all the removing files/renaming branches/and re-cloning repos ...

Since you posted an update that does something to change the situation entirely, I'll approach them each in turn to detail exactly what you would need to do for each of these cases to commit your changes to the remote.

### Case 1: No git, made changes, now you need git to push

Let's start with the initial situation prior to the update. You've copied the repo to a local directory without cloning (e.g. downloaded the zip of the repo). This, obviously, did not copy the git history or anything of that nature. Next, you modified some of the files locally. Now, you want to commit those changes to the remote branch *main*.

The things you did:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://...
git fetch origin
git add .
```

At this point, your changes are *staged* for commit on the branch *master* to the local repo. You've also added the remote *origin* and fetched it's contents. However, the remote is named *main*, so committing now will commit to *master*, and you will need to merge (which you don't want to do).

#### Option 1: Rebasing

1. First, rename your branch. Your changes are staged, but since you are just renaming a branch and not switching, it will be fine. The changes will go with you. Call `git branch -M main`. This will rename your current branch *master* as *main*.
2. Second, set the upstream of main to be the remote *main*. Do this by calling `git branch -u origin main`.
3. Third, you want to merge your changes into main without adding a "merge commit". The way to do this is with a rebase. Call `git rebase main origin/main`.
4. Since you seem to have conflicts with the remote *main*, as indicated in your other comments, you will need to resolve those here as well. Once you have resolved all the conflicts, you will call `git add -u` to add all the fixed files and the `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase. If your local branch is far behind the remote repo, you may need to do this several times.
5. Since you do not have a shared history with the remote, the rebase may fail with the same "refuse to merge unrelated histories" error. If this happens do the following: `git merge --allow-unrelated main --no-commit`, `git commit -C HEAD`, `git rebase --continue`
6. Once the rebase is complete, you can safely push your changes to the remote *main* and it will look nice and clean. `git push origin main`

#### Option 2: Stashing

Stashing is pretty dirty, so I didn't want to mention it, but depending on how far back your changes are from *origin/main*, this could be easier.

Starting from the same situation ...

1. Reset staged files with `git reset`. This will just unstage all staged changes.
2. Stash all your changes with `git stash`.
3. Check out the remote main `git checkout origin/main`
4. Make your own main on origin/main `git checkout -b main`
5. Pop your stashed changes `git stash pop`.
6. Again, you may have some conflicts here, but if your far behind origin/main, you should get them all at once rather than piecemeal (which is good? maybe?).
7. Once you resolve the conflicts, it's pretty standard `git add -u`, `git commit -m "I did it the dirty way ..."`, `git push origin main`.

### Case 2: No git, made changes, made clone of repo, force copied files into new cloned repo dir, now you need git to force push changes

This is bad. Don't do this. What this does is completely overwrites anything that was changed in the remote. This is exactly what those "merge conflicts" were trying to prevent you from doing. In fact, this is exactly what git was built to help you do.

For example, if someone else commited changes to file x, and you changed stuff in file x that now conflicts with what is in the remote. Git will tell you "hey, there's a conflict here. You and someone else both edited this file." Now it's your job to go fix it to make sure you don't clobber what the other person did.

By copying your files into the new dir, you are basically saying, "f that dude. Take away all their changes and replace them with mine", which is pretty rude.

If you really want to do this, then ...

So now you are in a repo that is cloned from remote. Your branch will be *main* since that is what is at remote, but you can do a `git checkout main` just in case. Now you copy in your files (again, bad, but I'm rolling with it).

At this point, you can simply do the following:

1. `git add -u` to stage the changes
2. `git commit -m "my cool changes"` to commit them (change the comment)
3. `git push origin main` to push them to the remote.

Since you've cloned the remote, all your branches should automatically be targeting the correct remotes.

Comment: I have already tried this, it says: fatal: branch 'main' does not exist

Comment: This indicates you're local branch is named different than the remote, like matt says below. This would happen if you are using git from the command line (which uses master as the default branch in some versions). Either change your local name to match the remote, like matt says below, or use "git push origin master:main" to temporarily get around the issue.

Comment: Yes, then maybe I could simply rename the branch from master to main at some step?

Comment: Yes, you can rename a branch by doing the following "git branch -M main". This will rename the current branch to main.

Comment: I have found a somewhat similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162158/cant-change-my-master-branch-to-main-locally on renaming the (empty) branch. But seems like using this method I need to make a first commit to a local branch which would create a merged commit. Can't I really do a simple commit?

Comment: First let's clarify the situation. You have both committed changes in a local repo to a branch master, and uncommited changes to several files. You are trying to push both the commited and uncommited changes to a github repo named origin and branch named main. Your local repo is not a clone of the remote and does not share any history with the remote. Is that correct?

Comment: I think it's not correct. I'ts very simple. I have a local directory which contains all the repository files probably downloaded zipped from github and then modified. So I want to commit these changes.

Comment: I want to push only uncommited files. There is no local branch, no .git directory. And there is a remote repository with main branch from where it was downloaded zipped and then modified. I want to commit only these changes and keep on changing and commiting from within this directory.

Comment: Thanks, this  now looks very comprehensive. In my case, there were no changes made on remote by anyone, changes were only on my side, not sure why gotten those conflict errors. It was really safe to go with case 2 but still wanted to learn how to do this properly.

Comment: While I'm glad I could help, I can't help but stress that the rout you choose is not what git was meant for. If are wanting to take that kind of approach with git, then git is not the right tool for you and your team. Please do your best to understand how to use git in the way it was intended if you want to use it effectively.